# How to change syntax for calling functions in python?

Tags: python, function, methods, syntax, call

Functions are often applied to arguments in this way: `func(arg)`. However, if argument is very long (for example a combination of other functions), the code is more readable if the following syntax is used: `x.sun()`. Is there a trick in python that allow to switch from the first syntax to another one.

For example, in my particular case I would like to be able to use `x.list()` in stead of `list(x)`.

Comment: Please keep in mind that 'is more readable' is quite a subjective statement. Also, as this is not the default manner in which python does this, you might not want to do this if your code is to be used by people other than just you.

Comment: Actually one is a function and the other a method on an object. The difference is more than just syntax, it's design.

Comment: If the argument is too complex an expression, then save its value in a variable and call a function on that.